# How to connect to a specified database table based on a form value

Tags: sql, database, forms, connect

I've got a form that asks the user for input. I need to take what that user has entered and connect to the related database table.
**For example: Say the form asks the user to input a city in a certain state. And i've got a table for every city in that state. How do i take the value (the city) that the user entered and connect to that specific table?**

*I have one database with a table for each city*
I am trying to organize information based on the city someone lives in. for example: If the form asks for 3 entries: City, Name, and Phone number. I want the user to type in the city they live in- then i want their Name and Phone number to be injected into the SQL Database pertaining to their city.

Comment: Do you mean that you have separate tables for each state?

Comment: It's more like this..Say that you only have one database- call it California. And you have a separate table for every city within California. I want to connect to the specific table (city) based on the city that the user selects.

Comment: Why do you have separate tables for cities? Thats not good design.

Comment: How else would i do it? I am trying to organize information based on the city someone lives in. for example: If the form asks for 3 entries: City, Name, and Phone number. I want the user to type in the city they live in- then i want their Name and Phone number to be injected into the SQL Database pertaining to their city.

Comment: Every city has the same properties. You make one table for all the cities.

Comment: But i want things to be more organized- That just seems really cluttered. My main concern is if i ever want to echo the data of everyone living in Silicon Valley, CA- I would like to just echo the contents of a table rather than querying the results to only display people who share the same city.

Comment: But actually, having one table for all of the cities might not be a bad idea. It would definitely fix the huge loading time i have when i open PHPMYADMIN.

Answer (score 1):

Eminent, a table in SQL represents a 'type' of object, e.g. you will need a table for city, as well as a table for state. You will have something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

first of all, which database engine are you using?

second you don't connect directly to a table. You connect to a server\database and then you have access to all the tables on that server\database.

Your question is very confused, please give more details

Comment: I'm using an SQLDatabse version 5.5.21-55.
Basically i need to connect to a certain table within the database so i can edit the rows/columns of that specific table.